# Linear algebra, are my steps to compute cost function value correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, neural-networks

Reading this :

[image]

From http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/09_Neural_Networks_Learning.html

Cost function for a single training example is given as :

cost(i) = $ y^i \; log \; h_\theta(x^i) + (1 - y^i)  log \; h_\theta (x^i)$

Are my steps to work out the cost for a single training example correct ? :

cost(1) = $ y^1 \; log \; h_\theta(x^1) + (1 - y^1)  log \; h_\theta (x^1)$

$
x^1 =  
$

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}

$
y^1 =  
$

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}

$ h_\theta(x) = 1 / 1+e{^-\theta Tx} $

Working this out :

Randomly initialise $\theta$ values to \begin{bmatrix}
    .1 \\
    .1 \\
    .1
\end{bmatrix}

cost(1) = $ y^1 \; log \; (1 / 1 + e - ^{\begin{bmatrix}
    .1 \\
    .1 \\
    .1
\end{bmatrix}^T  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} } )+ (1 - y^1)  log \; (1 / 1 + e - ^{\begin{bmatrix}
    .1 \\
    .1 \\
    .1
\end{bmatrix}^T  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} } )$

Substituting is this correct ? :

cost(1) = $ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} \; log \; (1 / 1 + e - ^{\begin{bmatrix}
    .1 \\
    .1 \\
    .1
\end{bmatrix}^T  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} } )+ (1 - \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix})  log \; (1 / 1 + e - ^{\begin{bmatrix}
    .1 \\
    .1 \\
    .1
\end{bmatrix}^T  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} } )$

cost(1) = $ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} \; log \; (1 / 1 + e - ^.2 )+ (1 - \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix})  log \; (1 / 1 + e - ^.2 )$

cost(1) = $ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} \; log \; (1 / 1 + .82 )+ (1 - \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix})  log \; (1 / 1 + .82 )$

cost(1) = $ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} \; log \; .549+ (1 - \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix})  log \; .549$

cost(1) = $ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} \; -.26+ \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix} -.26$

cost(1) = $ \begin{bmatrix}
    .74 \\
    .74 \\
    -.26
\end{bmatrix} \;+ \begin{bmatrix}
    -.26 \\
    -.26 \\
    .74
\end{bmatrix}$

cost(1) = $ \begin{bmatrix}
    .48 \\
    .48 \\
    .48
\end{bmatrix}$